# StreamReader path using * - Illegal Characters in Path

Tags: c#, streamreader

I need to use StreamReader like this

```
StreamReader fichRecheio = new StreamReader(@"G:\C#Projects\folder1\*.tl2",System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

But it gives me an error : 
Unhandled Exception - Illegal Characters in Path
If i put the name of the file instead of the * works ok.
There is only one file in that directory.I just don´t know the name, just extension.
Thanks

Comment: Isn't it clear?  **Illegal Characters in Path**. You can not use `*` in file/dir name.

Comment: You have to create a loop, using Directory.GetFiles and specifying your wildcards to get all the files you want and then process them one by one with the StreamReader.

Comment: If you only know the extension of the file, use `Directory.GetFiles(@"G:\C#Projects\folder1\", "*.t12", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)` to get a `string[]` array of matching filename(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly why not do it like this:

Use Directory.EnumerateFiles() method instead.

```
var sourceDirectory = @"G:\C#Projects\folder1\"
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.tl2");

foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
   StreamReader leFiles = new StreamReader(currentFile, System.Text.Encoding.Default);  
}
```

Comment: But there is only one file to read in that directory. Not multiple files

Comment: If you don't know the name of the file (just the extension) then I don't think there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, `*` is used for wildcard matching of multiple files. Specify a single filename:

```
StreamReader fichRecheio = new StreamReader(@"G:\C#Projects\folder1\example.tl2",System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

Comment: But i need to use like this...  I need to StreamReader to read the file with that extension, I don´t know the file name.

Comment: So you need to use `Directory.GetFiles()` and supply `*.t12` as the search pattern. `StreamReader` can only deal with a single specified file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to open multiple files with a single stream, that's not possible.

You have to specify the exact file name with which you are trying to connect reader as:

```
 StreamReader fichRecheio = new StreamReader(@"G:\C#Projects\folder1\test.tl2",System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying use a wildcard to search for files with a specific pattern in the name, use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("*.tl2")` which returns an array of paths that you can enumerate through.

```
string[] FilePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("*.tl2");

foreach (file in FilePaths)
{
//process the file
}
```